# Apply autofitwindow only to tables that exceed page width

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm very new to vba and word macros. I'm having an issue where I'm exporting a document to word and a few of the tables exceed page width. I was wondering if there is a way to check if each table is within page width and, if not, ONLY target the tables that have exceeded page width and auto fit those tables to the window.

Here is some code that autofits every table in the document to the window:

```
Sub tablesAutoFit()

Dim table As table

For Each table In ActiveDocument.Tables

table.AutoFitBehavior (wdAutoFitWindow)

table.AllowAutoFit = False

Next

End Sub
```

I want to know if there is a way to just autofit the tables that exceed page width, not every table in the document.

Thanks

Comment: Please provide (minimal) code you're using (as per [mcve]) so that we can repro the situation. Also provide details about the kinds of tables. ANY table can "exceed" page width if the cells are wide enough, no matter what they contain - we need to understand the logic. But I have to wonder if you've thoroughly tested the `wdAutoFitBehavior` parameter of the `Tables.Add` method?

Comment: I just edited the question to include some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to determine whether a table "fits" on a page it's necessary to determine the table width and compare it to the page width. The following example assumes the table contains no horizontally merged cells, so that the columns can be addressed. If that's not the case, you need to "walk" the cells in a(ny) row to get their widths.

```
Sub TableWidth()
    Dim tbl As Word.Table
    Dim col As Word.Column
    Dim tblWidth As Double, pgWidth As Double
    Dim pgSetup As Word.PageSetup

    Set pgSetup = ActiveDocument.PageSetup
    pgWidth = pgSetup.PageWidth - pgSetup.LeftMargin - pgSetup.RightMargin
    Set tbl = ActiveDocument.Tables(1)
    For Each col In tbl.Columns
        tblWidth = tblWidth + col.width
    Next
    If pgWidth < tblWidth Then
        tbl.AutoFitBehavior wdAutoFitWindow
    End If
    Debug.Print tblWidth, pgWidth
End Sub
```

Comment: That's great! I did edit the code so that it would iterate through each table in the document. But that does solve my problem. Thank you!

Comment: Just to let ya know AllowAutoFit has to be set to False after AutoFitWindow in order for the macro to work.

Comment: @JosueMendez Ah? The macro worked for me, but I didn't run it on multiple tables... I'm not exactly sure, therefore, of the context of your comment. I'd like to include the information in the Answer, for the sake of completeness, but I need to understand it better, first...